# how to insert % symbol in a statement without intending comment?

Tags: percent-sign

I wish to insert a % symbol in a line. But the rest of the statement goes missing since % is usually intended for comment. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: `\%` ............

Comment: This is listed in Table 1: LaTeX 2e Escapable “Special” Characters of [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should escape it: `\%`.

For "special character" using `\` will say to TeX to not understand it as a special character but a classic one that will be printed in the document.

This is the case for `#` or `_` too for exemple.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `\SI{70}{\percent}` command from the `siunitx` package.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a backslash before % such as to write 70% we have to use `70\%`.

Comment: There should be some tiny space between the number and the “unit”, i.e. `70\,\%`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Not generally used; it's not a unit.

Comment: @egreg That is why I put unit in quotation marks.  Also a quick web search revealed that there is [no consensus](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/3284) on the space.

Comment: This kind of spaces is automatically done with the `siunitx` package.